# Cannot subscribe to Capture Data Changes (CDC) channel using EMP Connector

Tags: streaming-api, change-data-capture

I'm trying to implement CDC using the [EMP Connector sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_emp_connector.htm).

I run it against the sandbox and try to subscribe to channels such as `/data/ChangeEvents` or `/data/AccountChangeEvent`.

I always get this error:

> com.salesforce.emp.connector.CannotSubscribe: Unable to subscribe to [/data/ChangeEvents:-2] [https://xxx--QA.csyyy.my.salesforce.com/cometd/43.0] : 400::**The channel specified is not valid {/data/ChangeEvents}**

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you enabled CDC from settings?

Comment: You are correct. Our admin didn't do it.Now it works perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CDC events only fire when you enable CDC from Setup.

You can enable Change Data Capture from Setup -> Change Data Capture and Select Objects for whom you wanna enable CDC

Comment: I have been trying to receive the CDC events via EMP Connector in the terminal, but it does not work. The subscription is successful though. My guess is that Salesforce is not generating the CDC events. However, I tested with PushTopic and it seems to work just fine. Any idea why this may be happening?